# How to purchase multiple quantity of one product via In App Purchase at once in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a product on iTunesConnect and I want to send one copy of that product to each of my multiple friends (say 10 for now, as number will be dynamic) in one go. Is it possible to show the Purchase Pop Up with the total number of copies if that product with combined price OR I will have to purchase the purchase equal to the number of copies I want to send to my friends.

Comment: Is this a consumable purchase then?

Comment: @Wain Yes it is Consumable!

Answer (score 3):

`SKMutablePayment` has a `quantity` property that you can set in order to purchase multiple items with a single request.

Comment: But will it allow to purchase multiple quantity of single item? Like I want to send "Coin" to my 10 friends but since the product is one so will it allow to send 10 coins to 10 friends in one go?

Comment: If the product is consumable (otherwise it makes no sense to want to purchase multiples)